# Swift - Principiante Cuando utilizar StoryBoards y cuando no?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy iniciándome en esto de Swift y tengo una duda que no me la puedo sacar de ninguna manera, veo en muchos cursos que los profesores crean vistas con archivos .swift que si no me equivoco es con SwiftUI, pero también crean StoryBoard y simplemente no entiendo, para que crear un storyboard, no se supone que puedo hacer toda la app solo con swiftUI? o necesito siempre tener un storyboard? las aplicaciones del mundo real como es que las realizan?

Estoy super perdido en este sentido necesito que alguien me aclare esos conceptos de manera concreta, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Nunca uses Storyboards, fueron hechos por el mismisimo lucifer. SwiftUI es el futuro, pero aun sin eso, tambien podrias hacerlo con el UIKit programaticamente. Si eres programador, programa! no arrastres cosas con el mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI es el futuro de la programación para Apple, y tiene grandes ventajas pero los storyboards siguen utilizándose en la mayoría de las aplicaciones actuales. Si deseas dedicarte profesionalmente al desarrollo iOS deberías conocer como utilizar ambas formas de crear una aplicación, ya que seguramente te encuentres con aplicaciones heredadas que no han sido diseñadas para SwiftUI, incluso algunas todavía en Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amig@ yo también estoy iniciando un poco con swift, pero según lo que e podido revisar, StoryBoards estan quedando desactualizados ya que es por medio de interfaces y programabas para una sola version de IOS, desde que inicio SwiftUI las cosas cambiaron drásticamente ahora si tu programas ahi significa que te van a correr tanto en versiones pasadas como en futuras y ahi puedes programar una vez para cualquier tipo de equipo IOS,

Suerte!!!